# Get parameter passed in jenkins build

Tags: jenkins

I am running external script to trigger parameterized Jenkins job.Basically I want to run parallel jobs. But I don't want to execute the job with same parameter is already running. I guess, That logic I have write into the external script. Now my question is, let's say Job is running with parameter A, B and C. In this case I should be able to trigger Job with parameter D, E,F but at the same I should not able to trigger job with A, B and C parameter as it is already running. To achive that I need to know running build with their parameters. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to get the current build ID (the build in running state).

You can have a look [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/309848/how-to-check-the-build-status-of-a-jenkins-build-from-the-command-line) how to do that.

Then use this id do get the parameters of the job.

Considering **18** the build ID

```
http://your-jenkins-server.domain.com/jobName/18/parameters/
```

Compare the parameters between current build and possible next build to trigger.

I advise you to read [Jenkins API](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Remote+access+API) for general information and also take a look at

```
http://your-jenkins-server.domain.com/jobName/api
```